# Passing extra parameters for mysql query callback function in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run a mysql query using node js and in the callback function I want to pass some additional parameters.

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++)
{
    connection.query ('select * from products where category=' + categories[i] , function (err, products) {
            if (products != undefined && products.length > 0) 
            {
                // want to do some processing based on product data and category name   
            }
    });
}
```

In the above code, how can I pass category name to the callback function? I know I can do a join in the sql query and that will give me the data in the products but just want to know if there is anyway of passing the data in the callback function.

Comment: Closures.......

Comment: Not sure how to do it in my case but will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `const`. Also, never construct queries by simply concatenating strings with variables.

Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++)
{
    const categoryName = categories[i];
    connection.query('select * from products where category = ?',
                     [categoryName],
                     function (err, products) {
      if (err)
        throw err;
      if (products.length > 0)
      {
        // use `categoryName`
      }
    });
}
```

You may also want to consider using a database connection pool instead of just a single connection (since all queries are queued and only one query can be executing at any given time per connection).

Comment: If you use const, wouldn't the category variable be set only once? The first one?

Comment: It is set once (*per iteration*), but it's limited to the scope of the `for` block (whereas `var` is limited to the closest `function` scope, which is much wider). If you're going to modify the value elsewhere within that block, you'd have to use `let` *or* use a closure + `var`.

Comment: I tried it but the value does not seem to change once set in the for block.